# Undefiend Variable In yajra

Tags: php, laravel

Below is the code to show current exam to student.If he already applied then he cannot apply for the same.When user logged in I stored there value in Session.put('Student.id',$user[0]->id).Now when i run below code I am getting the error:

> undefiend variable:$admission_id in alert(I used YAJRA DATATABLE).

```
**$admission_id** = Session::get('student.id');
$exam=DB::table('exam')->where('id_exam_category','2')->get();
return Datatables::of($exam)
          ->addIndexColumn()
          ->addColumn('exam_name', function($row){
              return $row->exam_name;
            })
        ->addColumn('action',function($row){
              $stu=DB::table('exam_student')
                ->where('id_exam',$row->id)
                ->where('admission_id',**$admission_id**)
                ->get();
        if(count($stu) > 0) {
            $ret='<button class="btn btn-block btn-default" disabled>Appered <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>';
        }else{
             $ret='<a href="'.url('instruction',[$row->id]).'" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Start <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>';
        }
        return $ret;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```

Even if i print $admission_id...It is printing. Session.id has student id and not empty..
Any Suggesstion ?
Thank You

Comment: In which file and in which line you are getting error, also mention line in given code ?

Comment: I am getting error in view as an alert

Comment: One more thing...If I directly write session->get('student.id') in the query I am getting the result but when I am assigning the session to variable its not giving me result

Comment: share your view file code ?